# How to debug Outlook web add-in in Windows native Outlook 2016?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I am developing a web add-on for Outlook, and during testing I've found a bug that only manifests within a native Windows Outlook applicaiton (in my case, Outlook 2016), but not within a browser.  Is there a way to troubleshoot (inspect, console log, etc.) the add-on from inside of Outlook 2016?

Comment: Is your computer default to open it in the web version? My default is desktop, and when I hit 'start' in VS I open in desktop (with breakpoints, etc. full control).

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio.  Is that required?  I typically do all of my development on a mac, so this is new territory for me.

Comment: Oh, ok different dev technique. Ignore that... That would only apply for VS. My apologies for assuming.

Comment: Vorlon.js looks like it might be useful.  https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac?product=outlook.  I'll give it a try soon and post it as an answer if it works.